# Typescript conditional breakpoints don't work in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and using Web Essentials. Typescript conditional breakpoints don't get set and I get an error:

*The breakpoint cannot be set. The condition cannot be set.*

this was my condition:

```
this.rightDown
```

and ticked

"is true"

any ideas?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript 0.8.1.1 and the latest Web Essentials 2012 (v2.2+) ?

Comment: yes indeed. still stuck :(

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, using Web Essentials 2012 2.4.5 & ReSharper 7.0.

Perhaps as a temporary workaround, the source maps works fine in Chrome.